# How to implement error checking parsing JSON in a for loop

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to parse this JSON from the tvmaze api. The JSON that is returned has one object as `None`. This is causing the `for` loop to break. How can I catch this error and skip it?

The simple code looks like this:

```
import requests,re,json


url = "http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/1/seasons"
html = requests.get(url).json()
for season in html:
    images = season['image']
    test = images['medium']
    print test
```

This results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/test_maze.py", line 7, in <module>
    if 'medium' not in images:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I can see that if I `print images`the result is:

```
{u'medium': u'http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/24/60941.jpg', u'original': u'http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/24/60941.jpg'}
{u'medium': u'http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/24/60942.jpg', u'original': u'http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/24/60942.jpg'}
None
```

I have tried multiple versions of `if 'medium' not in images`, but I get this error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: Your `if 'medium' not in images:` line is not present in the code you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test for a non-empty object first:

```
for season in html:
    images = season['image']
    if not images:
        continue
    test = images['medium']
```

`not images` is true if `images` is `None`, an empty dictionary, `0`, or any [other object that tests as false](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

You could also explicitly test for `None:

```
if images is None:
    continue
```

or you could invert the tests:

```
if images and 'medium' in images:
    #  there is a medium image
```

or

```
if images is not None and 'medium' in images:
    #  there is a medium image
```